# Angular - how to reduce an array, based on some specific checks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an ordered array that I get from the DB, that looks something like:

```
     let myArray = [      
        {month: 1, visible: true},
        {month: 2, visible: false}, 
        {month: 3, visible: true}, 
        {month: 4, visible: false},
        {month: 5, visible: false}, 
        {month: 6, visible: true},
        {month: 7, visible: true},
        {month: 8, visible: false}, 
        {month: 9, visible: true}, 
        {month: 10, visible: false},
        {month: 11, visible: false},
        {month: 12, visible: false}
      ];
```

what I need to do, is to reduce this, to a new array, where the first object will be the first `month` that has property `visible = true` , then it will take all the months up the last object that has `month = true`

this means it will ignore months only if they are not in a sequence, so if they are not creating gaps.

In my above example, it would return all objects beside the last `3 (10, 11, 12)` because they are outside the sequence, which is created by the first `TRUE` and the last `TRUE` (in this case, `month 1` and `month 9`)

I hope I made myself clear, so how can I complete my reduce() ?

```
myArray = myArray
    .sort((a, b) => a.month - b.month)
    .reduce((arr, current, idx) => {

      return arr;
    }, []);
```

Desired output:

```
 let myArray = [      
            {month: 1, visible: true},
            {month: 2, visible: false}, 
            {month: 3, visible: true}, 
            {month: 4, visible: false},
            {month: 5, visible: false}, 
            {month: 6, visible: true},
            {month: 7, visible: true},
            {month: 8, visible: false}, 
            {month: 9, visible: true}
];
```

Comment: I did have an answer almost ready to go, so it was a bit of a cheat on my part ;)

Comment: could you write your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trivial to find the start position, but a bit trickier to find the end position.

I would take this approach:

1. find first index with a matching condition
2. find last index with a matching condition
3. return the slice from first to last

```
// accept an array of type T and a predicate
// the predicate indicates which items define the inner range
// the predicate is a callback - a function - that accepts an argument of type T and returns a boolean

private filterInner<T>(arr: T[], predicate: (t: T) => boolean): T[] {

  // use findIndex to find the first matching index for the predicate

  const first = arr.findIndex(predicate);
  if (first === -1) {
    // no matching items in array
    return [];
  }


  // loop backwards to find the last matching index for the predicate

  let last = first;
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= first; i--) {
    if (predicate(arr[i]) === true) {
      last = i;
      break;
    }
  }


  // return the portion of the range between the two indexes (inclusive)
  return arr.slice(first, last + 1);
}
```

In your case, you would use it like this:

```
myArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => a.month - b.month);
const filtered = this  
  .filterInner(myArray, x => x.visible);
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrpsct

### Additional reading

Some additional reading if some of these techniques are new to you:

- [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Predicates in javascript](https://codepen.io/Universalist/post/predicates-in-javascript)
- [Generics in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

### Javascript equivalent

This is the plain javascript equivalent without the Typescript noise.

```
function filterContiguous(arr, predicate) {
  const first = arr.findIndex(predicate);
  if (first === -1) {
    // no matching items in array
    return [];
  }

  let last = first;
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= first; i--) {
    if (predicate(arr[i]) === true) {
      last = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return arr.slice(first, last + 1);
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to find `last` by iterating the array backwards and `break` on the first match.

Comment: thank you for the answer, could I ask you please to comment a bit the first and second part, which are pretty new to me (the filtering function you create!) thank you for the help!

Comment: @AJ989 I've added some comments. Let me know if there are still some bits you would like explaining. I appreciate it's probably a  bit confusing if some of these techniques are new. It's fairly simple javascript at its core, with some confusing typescript thrown in for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can find index till your should be sliced and then just take this array:

```
const findMaxIndex = arr => {
    let prev = 0;
    for (let index = arr.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        prev = index - 1;
        if (arr[index].visible == false && arr[prev].visible !=  false)
          return index;
    }
    return -1;
};

console.log(myArray.slice(0, findMaxIndex(myArray)));
```

An example:

```js
let myArray = [
        {month: 1, visible: true},
        {month: 2, visible: false},
        {month: 3, visible: true},
        {month: 4, visible: false},
        {month: 5, visible: false},
        {month: 6, visible: true},
        {month: 7, visible: true},
        {month: 8, visible: false},
        {month: 9, visible: true},
        {month: 10, visible: false},
        {month: 11, visible: false},
        {month: 12, visible: false}
];

let maxIndex = 0;

const findMaxIndex = arr => {
    let prev = 0;
    for (let index = arr.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        prev = index - 1;
        if (arr[index].visible == false && arr[prev].visible !=  false)
          return index;
    }
    return -1;
};

console.log(myArray.slice(0, findMaxIndex(myArray)));
```